# Strange numbers in java socket output

Tags: java, sockets

I have small test app:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("jeck.ru", 80);

PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), false);
pw.println("GET /ip/ HTTP/1.1");
pw.println("Host: jeck.ru");
pw.println();
pw.flush();

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

String str;
while ((str = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

It`s output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 13 Mar 2010 22:06:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Server  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 13 Mar 2010 22:06:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Sat, 13 Mar 2010 22:06:51 GMT

123
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Ваш IP</title>
</head>

<body>
        <div style='text-align: center; font: 32pt Verdana;margin-top: 300px'>
        Ваш IP &#151; 94.103.87.153     </div>
</body>
</html>

0
```

Whence these numbers (123 an 0) takes?

Comment: Format your code better, please.  Add four spaces at the beginning of each line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These numbers are a result of:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

See [Chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) for more details and links to specifications.